# Angular input [type]="'number'" always results in value being string

Tags: angular, property-binding

Normally, I would declare the input type this way (Which works great):

```
<input [(ngModel)]="input1" type="number" placeholder="Working"/>
```

How ever, I want the type to be dynamic, therefore I use property binding `[type]="objectType"`. To simplify the question, I used `[type]="'number'"`.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="input2" [type]="'number'" placeholder="Not Working"/>
```

Now the problem is that when ever I make a change to `input2`, it is converted to a string. That's not the case with `input1` - it remains the number which is the expected behavior. How can I use property binding for type and prevent it from converting to string?

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzttpk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known issue (see issue [#13243](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13243)).

A simple **workaround** for now is to use different inputs for each types :

```js
@Input() public myInputType: string;
```

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="value" type="number" *ngIf="myInputType === 'number'"/>
<input [(ngModel)]="value" type="text" *ngIf="myInputType === 'text'"/>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: This won't work either because the value is being stored in the model as either a number or string.

Comment: It works if your value is declared as `value: number | string;`

Comment: Thanks, it's kinda odd the issue is still opened from 2016. This fixed the issue and will do it for now.

Comment: No sorry I wasn't clear, if the input field is a text field, the value gets saved to your model as a string.  If it's a number type it gets saved as a number.  So if the user enters a value and then the type is switched dynamically, it will remain either a number or string in your model and you've just introduced another bug into your code.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2mryc

Comment: @BrianBurton Yes that's true. How ever the types I am getting are coming from an API and are locked afterwards. So there is no toggling with them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug that I've run up against as well, but the only solution right now is to manually cast the input value.

```
  logValues() {
    // Manually cast it as an integer (or float if need be)
    if (this.input2Type == 'number')
      this.input2 = parseInt(this.input2.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));

    console.log('input1 =>', this.input1);
    console.log('input1 type => ', typeof(this.input1));
    console.log('input2 =>', this.input2);
    console.log('input2 type => ', typeof(this.input2));
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to dynamically change input type of a field you can try this.
In your html

```
<input [type]="value">
<button (click)="onClick()">Change</button>
```

In your .ts file

```
value: string;
constructor(){
this.value = 'string';
}

onClick() {
  if (this.value == 'string') {
  this.value = 'number';
 }
else {
  this.value = 'string';
 }
}
```